# Why does somelist[len(somelist)] generate an IndexError but not somelist[len(somelist):]?

Tags: python, list, slice

I understand that `somelist[len(somelist)]` cannot access an index that is outside of the defined list - this makes sense.

But why then does Python allow you to do `somelist[len(somelist):]`?

I've even read that `somelist[len(somelist):] = [1]` is equivalent to `somelist.append(1)`

But why does slice notation change the fact that the index "len(somelist)" is still outside the range of the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).  There are specific rules around slicing of any iterable; of particular note is #4, emphasis mine:

> The slice of `s` from `i` to `j` is defined as the sequence of items with
>   index `k` such that `i <= k < j`. If `i` or `j` is greater than `len(s)`, use
>   `len(s)`. If `i` is omitted or `None`, use `0`. If `j` is omitted or `None`, use
>   `len(s)`. **If `i` is greater than or equal to `j`, the slice is empty.**

Comment: Ok, that explains why an empty list is returned (as others have pointed out). But why does `somelist[len(somelist):] = [1]` allow you to append 1 to somelist? Isn't the equivalent of the previous command just `[] = [1]`? I apologize, I'm not trying to be dense.

Comment: If `i` >= `j`, the slice is empty (has no items currently) but it is not an empty list object; it is still a slice starting at `i`, and assigning a list to it removes its current items (there aren't any) from the list and inserts the items in the assigned list at position `i`.

Comment: For example, suppose I set `x = range(5)`, and then assign the slice `x[3:2] = [8,7,6]`, `x` will now be `[0, 1, 2, 8, 7, 6, 3, 4]`. That's the same situation; there's nothing special about slice assignment in the `i` = `len(s)` case.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing at the index `len(somelist)` (list indices start at 0 in python). Therefore, trying to access a non-existing element raises an error.

However, list slicing (with the `myList[i:]` syntax) returns a new list containing the elements including and after `i`. Since there are no elements in the list at index `i` (or after), an empty list is returned

Comment: @AlexKrycek: Yes.  Assigning to a slice is not the same as just reading the slice.

Answer (score 1):

From [the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html):

> Degenerate slice indices are handled gracefully: an index that is too large is replaced by the string size, an upper bound smaller than the lower bound returns an empty string.

So an index > list size is automatically corrected, and `somelist[len(somelist):]` returns the elements after the last one, ie *nada*.